# How to change to the next above directory

Tags: directory

I really would like to know how to change directory to the next file, using 2 dots `(/..)`.

I can go back to previous directory but how to do something like that to go to the next directory WITHOUT THE NAME OF THE FILE PLEASE!

I know it is possbile with the name of the folder but my answer is different, please let me know.

Comment: Edit your question and discuss what you found when you googled it, and why none of what you found was useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

What O.S are you using? In linux ubuntu/Debian distributions (and probably in windows, not sure), you can enter the first child directory by simply typing`cd */`, this will change your current directory to the first child directory available in alphabetical order, example:

```
-/home
  -alan
    -desktop
    -music
  -alex
    -documents
    -pictures
  -lisa
```

Assuming your in `/home`, if you write `cd */` in the terminal you will be in `/home/alan`, because `-alan` is the first folder/directory available.

Comment: i am using windows OS and i tried what you suggested in command prompt but it is not working , however cd /* is working but whatever, i mean its function isnt the same as you told, could you suggest me another way please ?

Comment: What does cd /* do? keep in mind that I suggested cd **/, not cd /*, which I guess didn't do anything yes?? also, since you are in windows, you will probably have to especify the drive you are in (like C: or D:). So something like this in command prompt: C:  (hit enter)    cd */   (hit enter)